# AVD Emulator Error when starting

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, emulation

I am a beginner android developer and I had followed the instructions in the Quick Start and SDK Setup.  After following all the steps I attempted to run the Hello World sample application and when I run the project, I get the standard "emulator.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close." box.  I tried running the avd that I created in the AVD manager with the same results.  I also tried running the AVD from the command line, using "emulator.exe @my_avd".  I've tried 2.1 and 2.2 platforms.  I using Eclipse 3.5 SR2 with the android plug-in.  I am running Windows XP SP3, 512MB RAM, Intel Core 2 Quad on a virtual machine using VM-Ware.  My machine running the virtual machine has the 3GB max ram for a 32-bit machine.

Thanks in Advance,
Mark

---

In response to comments:

Android console says:
[2010-07-29 10:39:20 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2010-07-29 10:39:20 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2010-07-29 10:39:20 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2010-07-29 10:39:20 - HelloAndroid] Performing odog.andriod.example.helloandroid.HelloAndriod activity launch
[2010-07-29 10:39:20 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2010-07-29 10:39:20 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'

DDMS console says nothing.

I have not tried to run the emulator on the physical machine.  I'm trying to keep the Android development machine "clean".  My physical machine has Visual Studio 2010, 2008, 6, Windows Platform SDKs, DirectX SDKs of various versions as well as various versions of Eclipse for micro-controller and BlackBerry programming.  Little mucky .... needs to be formatted.

Comment: would you have any log from eclipse do provide?

Comment: Did you try to run the emulator directly on the physical machine ?

Comment: Response above ...  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have JDK 6 U21

Comment: FYI .... emulator works on physical machine using Eclipse 3.4.  Although I would still like some resolution to used on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems deleting and reinstalling all the packages in the Android SDK and AVD Manager worked.  Thanks for interest.